# My points On my character disappeared

Tags: select

Even when I am in edit mode and I want to adjust the points I cant anymore. I want to work on this in layout mode but none of the points are appearing

[image]

Comment: Try disabling the visibility of your solidify modifier. It probably creates a shell around your object, so you cannot see your vertices (points) in solid view.

Comment: How Do I Do That

Comment: In the bottom right corner of your screenshot you can see a solidify modifier. By pressing the icon that looks like a monitor you can disable the effect.

Comment: I just did that and I did notice a difference but it still won't allow me to select or adjust any of my points.

Comment: Do you have any Idea why?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168939/2214